# Create a range from the available values in R

Tags: r

In the below code `cut` function is being used and values are been specified but since this is a sample code its just hard coded for few but in my real case scenario we have more than 10 million records so identifying the ranges for the amount variable is quite difficult.

So my question is :

1. Is it possible to create a range from the values available for the amount in data.frame
2. For below code the groups are being displayed in exponential how to avoid it even after using `scipen=999`

options(scipen=999)

```
id = seq(1:30)
amount = c(30185, 33894, 33642, 29439, 27879 ,52347, 4101, 5425,
            6541, 54589, 5214, 1000, 45000, 64125, 100021, 120000, 
            657412, 15224,4578, 3639, 10000, 48781, 64484, 5020,
            15001, 105050, 14521, 59822, 42871, 32542)

df = data.frame(id, amount)
df$group = cut(df$amount,c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000))
```

**Output for df**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the function `cut` do the work of choosing the cut points by providing a single integer *n* as input instead of specifying the cut points manually. The function will automatically create *n* equal length interval.

To adjust the number of digits used in the interval labels, set the optional input `dig.lab` to the maximum number of digits of your labels.

In your example, you could use the following:

```
df$group = cut(df$amount,breaks=7, dig.lab=6)
```

Result:

```
> df
   id amount             group
1   1  30185 (343.588,94773.1]
2   2  33894 (343.588,94773.1]
3   3  33642 (343.588,94773.1]
4   4  29439 (343.588,94773.1]
5   5  27879 (343.588,94773.1]
6   6  52347 (343.588,94773.1]
7   7   4101 (343.588,94773.1]
8   8   5425 (343.588,94773.1]
9   9   6541 (343.588,94773.1]
10 10  54589 (343.588,94773.1]
11 11   5214 (343.588,94773.1]
...
```

*Edit*: To have more regular labels, set the cut points using the `seq` function. For example:

```
> df$group = cut(df$amount,breaks=seq(0,700000,25000), dig.lab=6)
> head(df)
  id amount         group
1  1  30185 (25000,50000]
2  2  33894 (25000,50000]
3  3  33642 (25000,50000]
4  4  29439 (25000,50000]
5  5  27879 (25000,50000]
6  6  52347 (50000,75000]
```

will create cut points at a distance of 25000 one another. Note that you need to specify the min and max of the range (here I set 0 and 700000)

Comment: for readability can it be made something like this sample -> `10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000` ?

Answer (score 0):

`cut(x, breaks)`, breaks either a numeric vector of two or more unique cut points or a single number (greater than or equal to 2) giving the number of intervals into which x is to be cut.

You can set `dig.lab` to avoid displaying in exponential.

```
df$group = cut(df$amount,c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000), dig.lab = 10)
```

Comment: can this be auto generated `10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000` this is just sample it can also be something like `10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000` etc....